# Excel - Creating a simplified "view" of a more complex table (macro?)

Tags: excel, vba

**Introduction:** Sheet1 in my excel workbook contains a "complex" table with about 130 columns and 2,5k rows.

**First issue:** 
Based on this table i want to create a simplified table("View") in Sheet2, which contains only e.g. columns A,C,F,G,I from the table in Sheet1.

This new "simplified" table should be updated when the table in Sheet1 is changed, e.g. in the form of a cell beeing edited, or a new row beeing inserted. Another way of approaching this would be to auto generate the table in Sheet2 everytime the user saves the workbook, or something similar.

**Second issue:**
The rows which contains a specific value in column F, lets say the value "XXX", should not be included in the Sheet2 table.

I'm not very experienced in more "advanced" excel functionality, but after researching the matter im leaning towards approaching this by creating a macro. Is this assumption correct? Or does excel have any other functionality to perform this task?

If creating a macro is the best approach, then any help would be much appreciated. I am currently playing arround with a test table with 4 rows, and copying two of these into a new worksheet. But i am having troubles with how to do this automatically, and exluding the rows with a specific value(Issue #2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following code: (Placed in the simple sheets module)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        .UsedRange.ClearContents
        '// Copy from data sheet too presentation sheet
        Sheet1.UsedRange.Copy .[a1]
        '// Filter all rows with xxx
        .Range("F:F").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="xxx", Operator:=xlAnd
        '// Delete all rows with xxx excluding the header
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        '// Remove the autofilter
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        '// Delete unwanted columns
        .Range("B:B,D:E,H:H").Delete
     End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reafidy! I tried it on the example i was testing on, and it worked perfectly. I will try it on the real thing now. First time i posted a question on stackoverflow, and i am really impressed by the quality of the answers, and how quick the question gets answered :) I also really appriciate the comments before every line of code. It makes it much easier to understand :)

Comment: Thanks Johan, good to see you using the Activate event too. :)

Comment: @Sebastian, I overlooked your comment.  Your most welcome!  Let me know if you need any further help and congratulations on your first successful question. +1.  By the way as you are a new member - remember to mark questions as answered if appropriate - that way everyone knows your question is solved and not to spend more time on it.  Thanks.

Comment: Tried the macro on my real table now, and it works great! I ran into a small problem, but google helped me fix it.

_The problem was : _A formula or sheet you want to move or copy contains the name 'XXXXXXXX', which already exists on the destination worksheet. Do want to use this version of the name?_

I fixed this with the following code:
Sub delNames()
For Each nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
ActiveWorkbook.Names(nm.Name).Delete
Next
End Sub

Is this a good approach?

Comment: Im kinda of a perfectionist, so want everything perfect :) Thats why i was wondering if :
1. it was possible to automatically add a filter to the first row in my new sheet?
2. it was possible to copy the width of the columns in the original Sheet to the copy sheet? The columns in my new sheet seem to all get the same column width

Comment: @Sebastian, use Copy from the old sheet and then PasteSpecial paste:= xlFormating into the new sheet. (or code to that effect, check the help on PasteSpecial

Answer (score 3):

The way I do this is using some code in the `on_activate` method of the worksheet.

That way, as soon as the user selects that sheet, the data is refreshed.

Here's pseudo code:

```
option explicit 'but thats just me.

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()  <<-- event of the simplified sheet.
    Worksheets("simplesheet").Cells.ClearContents
    Worksheets("alldata").Columns("A:A").Copy
    Worksheets("simplesheet").Columns("A:A").Select
    Worksheets("simplesheet").Paste
    'etc for all the relevant rows
End Sub
```

> Second issue: The rows which contains a specific value in column F, lets say the value "XXX", should not be included in the Sheet2 table.

Add the following to the event

```
    dim cel as range

    'for each goes in the wrong direction, we need to start down and go up.
    '1-select the REAL last cell in a range.
    Worksheets("simplesheet").Range("F65536").End(xlup).Select 'edit for Excel 2007
    Set cel = selection
    while cel.row > 0 
      if cel.value = "xxxx" then cel.entirerow.delete
      set cel = cel.offset(-1,0)
    wend
    Worksheets("simplesheet").Range("a1").select
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast and good answer Johan. I will try this first thing in the morning, and give a status report. The on activate approach seems just what i need!